# itemize inside todonote?

Tags: lists, itemize, todonotes

I'm using `todonotes` to make notes on my thesis. I'd like to be able to put some dot-points on a couple of the larger notes, like this:

```
\todo[inline]{
  \begin{itemize}
    \item blah blah blah
  \end{itemize}
}
```

But I get this error message:

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text>
            \par
l.9 }
```

Is there anything I can do to get around this, or is it basically not worth trying?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to use the `caption` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\todo[inline,caption={}]{
  \begin{itemize}
    \item blah blah blah
  \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

As described on page 12 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf) LaTeX will otherwise try to embed a `minipage` which leads to an error.

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly. Ah, the arcana of TeX. Thanks.

Comment: To me it prints a colon, as part of the caption. Any possibility to remove that colon?

Answer (score -1):

The colon problem occurs if the `prependcaption` option is set in the package options.

If you remove this option, the set caption (or the colon, if the caption is empty) is no longer displayed on the left.

Comment: This seems unrelated to the question...

Comment: This answers Zoltán Csátis question on how to remove the colon in the empty caption

I'm new to this forum and can't comment directly due to a lack of reputation.

Comment: Welcome! Please interact with the site elsewhere in order to get some rep. You only need one answer upvote or 2 question upvotes to get enough rep to comment :)